# input from user bydefault showing none in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

When i run this code, while taking price its showing None bydefault how can i opt None?

**Code below:**

```
t1 = input("Please Enter First Product: ")
t1_p = input(print(f"Please Enter {t1} Price: "))
t1_p = float(t1_p)

t2 = input("Please Enter Second Product: ")
t2_p = input(print(f"Please Enter {t2} Price: "))
t2_p = float(t2_p)

t3 = input("Please Enter Third Product: ")
t3_p = input(print(f"Please Enter {t3} Price: "))
t3_p = float(t3_p)

print(f"Average of {t1}, {t2} and {t3} prices is : {(t1_p+t2_p+t3_p)/3}")
```

Result in IDE highlightd should not come while entering values:

[image]

Comment: I would say the problem is the print inside input. Try `input("Please enter %s price: " % t1)`

Comment: Ahhh!! fine its working thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try get rid of the print:

```
t1 = input("Please Enter First Product: ")
t1_p = input(f"Please Enter {t1} Price: ")
t1_p = float(t1_p)
```